# Logout Alert Dialog (confirmation message) in Flutter with Firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

How can I show the confirmation message to ask the user if they want to logout in to the flutter?  When the user clicks "Yes", the page will navigate to the login page and the user status will be not logged in. When the user clicks "No", they will stay on the home page. The button should be a rounded button with text in the middle of the home page.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:login/Screen/Login/components/FormScreen.dart';
import 'package:login/Screen/Login/components/body.dart';
import 'package:login/Screen/Login/components/camera.dart';
import 'package:login/Screen/Login/components/uploadpage.dart';
import 'package:login/auth.dart';
import 'package:login/root_page.dart';

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  MyHomePage({this.auth, this.onSignOut});
  final  auth;
  final VoidCallback onSignOut;

  Icon cusIcon = Icon(Icons.search);
  Widget cusSearchBar = Text("Home Page");
  // show the dialog
  void _signOut() async {
    try {
      await auth.signOut();
      onSignOut();
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
            // search icon
            actions: <Widget>[
              IconButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  if (this.cusIcon.icon == Icons.search) {
                    this.cusIcon = Icon(Icons.cancel_outlined);
                    this.cusSearchBar = TextField(
                      textInputAction: TextInputAction.go,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                          border: InputBorder.none,
                          hintText: "Search Car Plate"),
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 16.0,
                      ),
                    );
                  } else {
                    this.cusIcon = Icon(Icons.search);
                    this.cusSearchBar = Text("Home Page");
                  }
                },
                icon: cusIcon,
              )
            ]),
        // Add Icon
        body: Center(
            child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: <Widget>[
              RaisedButton.icon(
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => FormScreen()),
                  );
                },
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0))),
                label: Text(
                  'Add Vehicle',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                ),
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.add,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
                textColor: Colors.white,
                splashColor: Colors.red,
                color: Colors.purple,
              ),
              RaisedButton.icon(
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => LandingScreen()),
                  );
                },
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0))),
                label: Text(
                  'Camera',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                ),
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.camera_alt,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
                textColor: Colors.white,
                splashColor: Colors.red,
                color: Colors.purple,
              ),
              RaisedButton.icon(
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => UploadPage()),
                  );
                },
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(30.0))),
                label: Text(
                  'Upload CSV File',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                ),
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.upload_file,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
                textColor: Colors.white,
                color: Colors.purple,
              ),
              FlatButton(
                  onPressed: _signOut,
                  child: new Text('Logout',
                      style:
                          new TextStyle(fontSize: 17.0, color: Colors.white)))
            ])));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

use showDialog

your code should look something like this:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:login/Screen/Login/components/FormScreen.dart';
import 'package:login/Screen/Login/components/body.dart';
import 'package:login/Screen/Login/components/camera.dart';
import 'package:login/Screen/Login/components/uploadpage.dart';
import 'package:login/auth.dart';
import 'package:login/root_page.dart';

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  MyHomePage({this.auth, this.onSignOut});
  final  auth;
  final VoidCallback onSignOut;

  Icon cusIcon = Icon(Icons.search);
  Widget cusSearchBar = Text("Home Page");
  // show the dialog
Future _signOut() async {
  try {
    //await auth.signOut();
    onSignOut();
    return await auth.signOut();
  } catch (e) {
    print(e);
  }
}


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
            // search icon
            actions: <Widget>[
              IconButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  if (this.cusIcon.icon == Icons.search) {
                    this.cusIcon = Icon(Icons.cancel_outlined);
                    this.cusSearchBar = TextField(
                      textInputAction: TextInputAction.go,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                          border: InputBorder.none,
                          hintText: "Search Car Plate"),
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 16.0,
                      ),
                    );
                  } else {
                    this.cusIcon = Icon(Icons.search);
                    this.cusSearchBar = Text("Home Page");
                  }
                },
                icon: cusIcon,
              )
            ]),
        // Add Icon
        body: Center(
            child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: <Widget>[
              RaisedButton.icon(
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => FormScreen()),
                  );
                },
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0))),
                label: Text(
                  'Add Vehicle',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                ),
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.add,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
                textColor: Colors.white,
                splashColor: Colors.red,
                color: Colors.purple,
              ),
              RaisedButton.icon(
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => LandingScreen()),
                  );
                },
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0))),
                label: Text(
                  'Camera',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                ),
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.camera_alt,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
                textColor: Colors.white,
                splashColor: Colors.red,
                color: Colors.purple,
              ),
              RaisedButton.icon(
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => UploadPage()),
                  );
                },
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(30.0))),
                label: Text(
                  'Upload CSV File',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                ),
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.upload_file,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
                textColor: Colors.white,
                color: Colors.purple,
              ),
              FlatButton(
                  onPressed: () {
              showDialog(
                  builder: (ctxt) {
                    return AlertDialog(
                        title: Text("Logout"),
                        content: Column(
                          children: [
                            Text("Do you Really want to logout?"),
                            Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                              children: [
                                RaisedButton(
                                  child: Text("Cancel"),
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    Navigator.pop(context);
                                  },
                                ),
                                RaisedButton(
                                  child: Text("Logout"),
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    _signOut().whenComplete(() =>
                                        Navigator.pushReplacement(
                                            context, yourLoginPage()));
                                  },
                                )
                              ],
                            ),
                          ],
                        ));
                  },
                  context: context);
            },
                  child: new Text('Logout',
                      style:
                          new TextStyle(fontSize: 17.0, color: Colors.white)))
            ])));
  }
}
```

Comment: hi, this method allows me to navigate to the login page but the _SignOut function does not work which is the user still logged on to the account when they log in one more time

Answer (score 1):

**showDialog** method should be enough for this case.

```
FlatButton(
  onPressed: () => showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (_) => Dialog(
      child: Container() //Your buttons here
      ,
    ),
  ),
  child: new Text(
    'Logout',
    style: new TextStyle(
      fontSize: 17.0,
      color: Colors.white,
    ),
  ),
);
```